# node: await with child process message handler

Tags: node.js, async-await, fork

I'm having trouble wrapping my hands around some async/await code I'm working on. Is there a way to make a child process's `message` handler async? Here is what my child process file looks like:

```
// child.ts
import { writeImage } from './generate-images'


const slowFunction = async (imageAttributes) => {
    console.log("inside child slowFunction....")
    await writeImage(imageAttributes, 0, true)
}

process.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('starting child....')
    slowFunction(msg)
    console.log('exiting child')
    process.exit()
})
```

I am calling it via `fork` in a big loop in the parent process because i need to perform this slow function a few thousand times, this is a dumbed down version of what im calling inside a big loop in the parent:

```
// parent.ts
const child = child_process.fork(path.join(__dirname, 'child.ts'))

child.send(Array.from(imageAttributes)[i])

child.on('exit', function () {
    console.log(`child exiting`)
    // do some cleanup
})
```

the problem is that all my forks keep exiting before `slowFunction` finishes because its an async function, but i cant add `async slowFunction(msg)` because the `process.on('message', ...)` handler is not async.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `process.on('message', ...)` an async function. No callbacks will be async by default.

```
process.on('message', async (msg) => {
    console.log('starting child....')
    await slowFunction(msg)
    console.log('exiting child')
    process.exit()
})
```

Comment: I completely forgot that it was a callback there and that I could just stick an `async` in front of it. Thank you!